# Residue and direction contour

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

Does the direction of the contour clockwise/anticlockwise effect the value of the residue?

Comment: Yes a Jordan curve has a specific orientation.

Comment: @mathreadler's answer is incorrect, a residue is a property of a function and not of contours. See meowmix's answer below.

Comment: It is not an answer but a comment addressing the obviously intended question of the contour affecting the value of integration. Meowmix's answer is excellent though as it addresses both things in a clear and concise manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it won't affect the value of the residue, because the residue is determined by a Laurent series expansion around a singularity, and determined solely by the function.

However, the value of a contour integral *itself* will be affected by the curve's orientation. More generally, if $I(\gamma,a_k)$ is the winding number of your contour $\gamma$ around singularity $a_k$, we get a similar, but more general statement of the residue theorem:

$$\oint f(z) dz = 2\pi i \sum \text{Res}(f, a_k) I(\gamma, a_k)$$

So, specifically, if your contour is reversed, the integral will be negative.

Comment: Which direction will  add the minus sign clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: If you switch from one to the other, the minus sign is added. It doesn't really matter which is negative.

Comment: What I mean is for example the function $\frac{3-z-z^2}{z}=\frac{3}{z}-1-z$ has residue equal to $3$. Now If I am asked to take contour clockwise or anticlockwise then which will make it $-3$?

Comment: The positively oriented curve will always be just $2\pi i$ multiplied by the sum of the residues, because the winding number is always 1. Meanwhile, the negatively oriented curve will be negative, because the winding number is negative.